# How to convert Buffer array to hex?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, arraybuffer

I am getting a Buffer array back in a JSON object when I call one of my API endpoints. I would like to convert this array to a more "usable" form (hex?) so I can compare them, etc. Here is what the object currently looks like:

```
"hash": {
  "type": "Buffer",
  "data": [
    151,
    14,
    51,
    26,
    46,
    52,
    5,
    151,
    99,
    107,
    38,
    188,
    138,
    180,
    76,
    56,
    108,
    214,
    135,
    213,
    125,
    134,
    105,
    139,
    129,
    236,
    206,
    157,
    67,
    1,
    12,
    12
  ]
}
```

How would I go about converting this array to a hex (or string, etc.) so that I can compare hashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a new [buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_buffer) and convert it into the format you need.

```
var o = {"hash": {
"type": "Buffer",
"data": [
  151,
  14,
  51,
  26,
  46,
  52,
  5,
  151,
  99,
  107,
  38,
  188,
  138,
  180,
  76,
  56,
  108,
  214,
  135,
  213,
  125,
  134,
  105,
  139,
  129,
  236,
  206,
  157,
  67,
  1,
  12,
  12
  ]
 }
}

console.log(new Buffer(o.hash,'hex').toString('hex'));
// 970e331a2e340597636b26bc8ab44c386cd687d57d86698b81ecce9d43010c0c
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an existing Buffer object, you can represent it as hex via:

```
myBuffer.toString('hex')
// '970e331a2e340597636b26bc8ab44c386cd687d57d86698b81ecce9d43010c0c'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Number.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString):

```js
var json = '{"hash": {"type": "Buffer","data": [151,14,51]}}';
var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
document.write("data: " + JSON.stringify(parsed.hash.data) + "<br>");
document.write("hex: ");
parsed.hash.data.forEach(function(b) { document.write(("00" + b.toString(16)).substr(-2)); });
```